# Low Battery Indicator Schematic Question

Tags: schematics, potentiometer

I have a question about this low battery indicator circuit:
[image]

I have already built the circuit, I just have a question about setting the potentiometer (R4). I want the LED to turn on at 6.1v, so how do I set the pot to do that? It's a stupid question, I've just never known how to do this properly. Thanks

Comment: Set your variable power supply to 6.1V and adjust.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abram Do I set the pot right when the Led turns on? Because the LED will remain on for about half of the pot's turn.

Comment: You set it for the threshold, yes.